# Does frequency need to be an integer in order for a signal to be periodic?

Tags: signal, signal-processing

Please help me understand periodicity. Why can \$T=\frac{1}{3}\$ be periodic but \$T=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\$ be aperiodic?

For example:

$$\cos(2\pi\times 3\times n) \Rightarrow \mathrm{periodic}$$

$$\cos(2\pi\times\sqrt{3}\times n) \Rightarrow \mathrm{aperiodic}$$

I understand that in order for a signal to be periodic, \$f=\frac{k}{n}\$ (frequency must be rational), but why is \$f=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}\$ not considered to be periodic?

Is it because \$\sqrt{3}=1.73205...\$ is not an integer?

Comment: I would like to know where you learned that irrational == aperiodic...

Comment: http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/cos-2-pi-sqroot-3-n-periodic-signal-q8893187

Comment: It was also annotated on a marked homework assignment that in order for a signal to periodic f=k/n (rational number). I'm in 3rd year electrical engineering. And confused. SOS.

Comment: cos(2*pi*sqroot(3)*n) appears to be periodic when graphed...

Comment: I keep finding lots of proof that the sum of a signal with a rational period and another signal with an irrational period is aperiodic, but nothing that proves that an irrational period itself is aperiodic.

Comment: @CaptainKoba, your linked source appears to only be available after paying $14.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that as \$\pi\$ is itself an irrational number, no matter what frequency you pick (unless it happens to be a rational multiple of \$\pi^{-1}\$, which would itself be irrational), the value for \$\omega\$ you feed into \$\cos(\omega t)\$ is irrational.

Comment: @ThePhoton Here's a screenshot:

https://imgur.com/Ae9hg0Y

Comment: I'd like to thank you all for your replies, although I am still quite confused on how to check for periodicity...

Comment: It would probably be more clear if you pointed out in you question that the context is discrete-time signals. I (and from the comments, others) didn't pick up on this just from the form of the signal. For a discrete time signal to be periodic, the period of the (notionally) underlying continuous-time signal should have mutual harmonic with the sampling signal . When the period of the underlying signal is not rational, this can't happen (as implied by Ignacio's comment).

Comment: Ok that I understand. Although it wasn't explicitly stated in the question that this was a discrete-time signal, I suppose I could have assumed that by the presence of an "n" instead of a "t" notation. Thank you all very much for helping.

Answer (score 8):

It's sort-of a semantic issue, while:

$$ x[n] = \cos(2 \pi 3 n) $$

is clearly periodic with period of 1, the other discrete-time signal

$$ y[n] = \cos(2 \pi \sqrt{3} n) $$

is not periodic.   There is no integer \$N\$ such that \$y[n+N]=y[n] \quad \forall n \$.  While \$y[n]\$ is not periodic, the continuous-time counterpart to it

$$ y(t) = \cos(2 \pi \sqrt{3} t) $$

**is** periodic because there **is** a real value \$T\$ such that \$y(t+T)=y(t) \quad \forall t \$.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but isn't the period of x[n] T=1/3?
if following the format cos(2*pi*f*n)... where f is 1/T..

Comment: actually, the period is 1.  $x[n]$ is discrete-time.  like $x_n$.  it has no meaning for $n$ that is not an integer.

Comment: Ok I understand that. However I don't understand how you came to the conclusion that y(t) is periodic.. Is this something that you must plot to see?

Comment: @CaptainKoba see [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63102/how-to-prove-periodicity-of-sinx-or-cosx-starting-from-the-taylor-seri) for how to provide continuous trig functions are periodic.

Comment: $y(t)$ is periodic with period $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, but for discrete-time signals to be periodic, their period must be an integer.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, y(t) is periodic simply because it is a sine/cosine function, and those functions always repeat. y[n] is not periodic because, despite the fact that is is a sine/cosine function, discrete-time signals cannot be periodic without an integer period.

Comment: something like that.